# No se refleja valor de propiedad luego cambiarla en Angular

Tags: html, angular, firebase

espero me puedan ayudar con este problema que tengo ya desde un tiempo.

Resulta que cuando cambio el valor de una propiedad luego de realizar una consulta a la BD (Firebase), no se ven reflejados los cambios si no hasta que hago click en cualquier parte de la pagina o incluso pasando el cursor por encima de los link del menu, ejemplo:

Tengo un spinner apagado

```html
<div *ngIf="loadingImage" class="spinner-border text-primary pr-5 m-5" id="kt_profile_avatar2" role="status">
   <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

inicialmente esta propiedad en el componente se encuentra en false
loadingImage = false;

Al subir una imagen enciendo el spinner (Esto lo hace), pero al finalizar la subida de la imagen, intento apagarlo, pero no se ve los resultados si no hasta que hago click en cualquier parte de la pagina (En alguna parte en blanco, sin link ni nada). El codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```js
public subirArchivo1() {
    this.loadingImage = true;
    const archivo = this.datosFormulario.get('archivo1');
    const referencia = this.firebaseStorage.referenciaCloudStorage(this.nombreArchivo1);
    const tarea = this.firebaseStorage.tareaCloudStorage(this.nombreArchivo1, archivo);

    tarea.percentageChanges().subscribe((porcentaje) => {
      if (Math.round(porcentaje) == 100) {
        console.log(Math.round(porcentaje));
        referencia.getDownloadURL().subscribe((URL) => {
          this.sPhotoINEfront = URL
            this.authService.updateProfileById(this.userData.uuid,{
              photoINEfront:{
                photo:URL,
                status:false,
              },
            }).then( () => {
              this.loadingImage = false;
              this.layoutUtilsService.showActionNotification(this.imageSave, MessageType.Update, 5000, true, true);
            });
        });
      }
    });

  }
```

Se puede ver que en el then() apago el spinner con this.loadingImage = false; pero pasa lo que comento más arriba.

La verdad no entiendo el por que pasa esto, si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: Puedes probar usando un Observable para que estes como a la espera del cambio, aca te dejo un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qhk1bb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Puedes añadir el código de `percentageChanges`, `getDownloadURL` y si se puede también `updateProfileById`para tener contexto de que estas haciendo y como ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Andres, gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente con lo que me comentas si logro apagar el spinner, pero la información (La imagen que subo a firebase) no se ve reflejada al momento de apagarse el spinner si no que se ve hasta que hago click en alguna parte de la pagina. Por ejemplo doy click para subir una segunda imagen y ahi es cuando se refleja la primera, o cuando paso el cursor por el menu, se refleja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este comportamiento puede pasar cuando se ejecuta código por fuera del contexto de Angular (lo que puede estar ocurriendo por parte del componente de firebase). Podrías intentar activar la detección de cambios en la vista de manera manual. Hay varias formas de lograr eso.

Una de ellas, es inyectando una instancia de `changeDetectorRef` en el constructor y llamar el método `detectChanges()`.

Comment: Gracias @JhonRayo99, si me funciono, muchas gracias.